# difference between apache2, apache2-threaded-dev and apache-prefork-dev

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

Whats the difference between different apache packages available.

1. apache2
2. apache2-threaded-dev
3. apache2-prefork-dev

will **sudo apt-get install apache2** will support both

apache-prefork-dev

apache2-threaded-dev

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are using Ubuntu

1. on my Ubuntu machine prefork was installed
2. apache2-threaded-dev is standard Apache package for Ubuntu - hybrid multi-process multi-threaded server (worker)
3. apache2-prefok-dev is non-threaded, pre-forking web server (prefork)

`sudo apt-get install apache2` will support prefork

Check yours by typing: `apache2ctl -V`

More about worker vs prefork: https://www.garron.me/en/blog/apache2-mpm-worker-prefork-php.html